# Apache RewriteRule doesn't works to suppress extensions, for other things, works

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a EC2 on AWS.
Configured the server (Apache 2, PHP 7.0, ...), enabled mod_rewrite.
I did this process a lot of times before, but never in Ubuntu 16.04.

After all, testing my server i observed:

- RewriteRules works, but not if it change the url or extensions.

Example:

This is **NOT WORKING:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    AcceptPathInfo On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

        RewriteRule ^dieta/([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?$ dieta.php?usuario_id=$1&dieta_id=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^diario/([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?$ diario.php?usuario_id=$1&data_registro=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^diario-fisico/([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?$ diario-fisico.php?usuario_id=$1&data=$2 [L,QSA]
        RewriteRule ^treino/([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?$ treino.php?usuario_id=$1&treino_id=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css         application/x-javascri$
</IfModule>
```

On this example:

www.link.com/dieta/50/20 <-- How Should be, doesn't works.

www.link.com/dieta.php/50/20 <-- Works.

This is **WORKING**:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)?/?([\w-]+)?/?$ index.php?class=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css         application/x-javascri$
</IfModule>
```

www.link.com/index.php/user/get <-- Works.

**Cases:**

- Wordpress permalinks, doesn't works (ERROR 404).
- Suppress extensions, doesn't works  (ERROR 404).
- Use with get variables, works.

I've configured following this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: That's quite a lot of config to debug by sight. You'll probably need to enable mod_rewrite logging and then show us the results of a request that is not working as you expect.